# ClassNotFoundException org hibernate engine FilterDefinition

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
ClassNotFoundException org hibernate engine FilterDefinition

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

I am new to hibernate+spring and don't know why this error arises while running my application.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I solve it.

If you are using below into your XML file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

change to `hibernate4` same as below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

From Hibernate 4+ use the  LocalSessionFactoryBean.

Answer (score -1):

check class file of hibernate local session factory belongs to relevant jar files;

```
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

change to

```
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```