# hibernateTemplate.save() command returns primary key but does not save to the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

The save command in Line 37 is not working, 
It can print the Primary Key , but not save a new record to the database.

[template save command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkLV1.png)

Git hub link - https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp

Comment: Can you please show complete stacktrace?

Comment: @akash I have added stack trace

Comment: Try after removing the driver class name property . This  [entry](https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/java/configs/hibernate.cfg.xml#L11)

Comment: @R.G Not working .  Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [configs/hibernateTemplate.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;

Comment: This is a new error . Modify the [line](https://github.com/DipanjanSG/BankingApp/blob/master/src/main/java/configs/hibernateTemplate.xml#L18) to org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean . [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036676/4214241)

Comment: @R.G I guess I also have to change the version of the jars, any input on that? I am getting new errors

Comment: you may need to do that . With all these errors you will not reach anywhere

Comment: @R.G Anything other than the version of the jars needs to be changed ? Specially in the XML. Specially Under the beans tag (in file hibernateTemplate.xml) ?

Comment: @R.G Issue solved . Had to change the Jar file versions. I question remains, in the file CreateAccount/CustomerDaoImpl.java the function ----> save(Customer customer); does not work. Do I have to commit it ? (the latest code has been pushed , kindly help me 1 last time).

Comment: Could you please update the question with what is not working . does not work is too broad a statement

Comment: @R.G Updated , the code has also been pushed to github

Comment: @akash Hi can you suggest solution to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059117/hibernatetemplate-save-command-fails-to-push-record-to-database

Comment: @R.G Can u help me out with this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62160377/jstl-foreach-unable-to-print-list-values